# Add rows to a Table in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to add a new row to an object table every time a button is clicked, but when I click the button it only edits and overwrite the same row

```
protected void btAgregaT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TableRow t = new TableRow();

    TableCell c = new TableCell();
    c.Text = DDLArticulos.SelectedItem.ToString();
    t.Cells.Add(c);

    TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
    c2.Text = TBCantidad.Text;
    t.Cells.Add(c2);

    tablaPed.Rows.Add(t);    

}
```

﻿

Comment: what is the type of `tablaPed` is that `DataTable`

Comment: `tablaPed.Rows.Add(DDLArticulos.SelectedItem.ToString(), TBCantidad.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new row to DataTable like this:

```
var newRow = tablaPed.NewRow();
newRow["Column1"] = "Value1";
newRow["Column3"] = "Value2";
newRow["Column3"] = "Value3";
tablaPed.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2:**
Basically you need to use ViewState to manage everything. Below i have mentioned for addition, in simple words you add, edit,delete records from ViewState and bind them to gridview.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Adding data to datatable
            DataRow t = tablaPed.NewRow();

            //adding data to row
            t["SrNo"] = "1";
            t["EmailId"] = "test@gmail.com";
            t["Password"] = "Password";

            //adding row to table
            tablaPed.Rows.Add(t);

            //saving databale into viewstate   
            ViewState["UserDetail"] = t;

            //bind Gridview  
            GridView1.DataSource = t;
            GridView1.DataBind(); 
        }
    }
```

Below the the funtion to call when add button is clicked:

```
private void AddNewRecordRowToGrid()
    {
        // check view state is not null  
        if (ViewState["UserDetail"] != null)
        {
            //get datatable from view state   
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["UserDetail"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //this will add previously added entries 
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    //add each row into data table  
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    //you can add data from textbox or other user control
                    drCurrentRow["SrNo"] = "2";
                    drCurrentRow["EmailId"] = "test@gmail.com";
                    drCurrentRow["Password"] = "Password";

                }
                //Remove initial blank row  
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                {
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[0].Delete();
                    dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();

                }

                //add created Rows into dataTable  
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                //Save Data table into view state after creating each row  
                ViewState["UserDetail"] = dtCurrentTable;
                //Bind Gridview with latest Row  
                GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

protected void btAgregaT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddNewRecordRowToGrid();  
}
```

I hope it helps you understand :)

---

Considering **tablaPed** as a **global DataTable object**.
Example below is the standard way of adding row to a table:

```
 //creating the table if you already have it then no need to add it.
 DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
 //Defining the table structure. If you already have defined DataTable you dont    need to define it either. 
 dt.Columns.Add("SrNo");
 dt.Columns.Add("EmailId");
 dt.Columns.Add("Password");

 //Creating a object of DataRow using object of desired table (Basically cloning a row)
 DataRow drNew = dt.NewRow();
 //Adding data to each row 
 drNew["SrNo"] = "1";
 drNew["EmailId"] = "test@gmail.com";
 drNew["Password"] = "Password";

 //adding this newly added row our table
 dt.Rows.Add(drNew);
```

In your case:

```
protected void btAgregaT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cloning the table row
    DataRow t = tablaPed.NewRow();

    //adding data to row
    t["SrNo"] = "1";
    t["EmailId"] = "test@gmail.com";
    t["Password"] = "Password";

    //adding row to table
    tablaPed.Rows.Add(t);    

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but the problem is that when I click the button (it's in a webpage), it only add's one row, and overwrittes it every time I click the button

Comment: Perfect, what's the difference between the ViewState and the Session? Can I use it too?

Comment: Sure, data stored in session variable will persist entire user session whereas viewstate will persist for that page only :). If i was any helpful don't forget to vote.

Answer (score 0):

The object of the `DataRow` must not be new, it should be refer to the DataTable which you already have globally.

```
protected void btAgregaT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TableRow t = tablaPed.TableRow();

    TableCell c = new TableCell();
    c.Text = DDLArticulos.SelectedItem.ToString();
    t.Cells.Add(c);

    TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
    c2.Text = TBCantidad.Text;
    t.Cells.Add(c2);

    tablaPed.Rows.Add(t);  
}
```

Also, check your code, if there is a `refresh()` or `clear()` method being called for the dataTable before adding new items. If you do find something, comment it, and try execution.